# Getting the PropertyAccessException for hibernate for the userId

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, hql

I have done an example for login using database in hibernate.My Xml and entity classes are
User.java:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity(name="User")
public class User {

    private Integer userID;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Date createdDate;

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     */
    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(Integer userID, String username, String password) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

}//end of class()
```

UserBooks.java:

```
public class UsersBooks {

    // Declaring all attributes
    private double userID;
    private String bookID;
    private String permission;

    // Constructors
    public UsersBooks() {
        super();
    }

    public UsersBooks(double userID, String bookID, String permission) {
        super();
        this.userID = userID;
        this.bookID = bookID;
        this.permission = permission;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    public double getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(double userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getBookID() {
        return bookID;
    }

    public void setBookID(String bookID) {
        this.bookID = bookID;
    }

    public String getPermission() {
        return permission;
    }

    public void setPermission(String permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
    }

    // Overriding toString()
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UsersBooks [userID=" + userID + ", bookID=" + bookID
                + ", permission=" + permission + "]";
    }//end of toString()

}//end of class
```

UserSocialInfo.java:

```
public class UserSocialInfo {


    private int socialID;

    private String loginProvider;
    private String loginProviderUID;
    private String UID;
    private String nickname;
    private String photoURL;
    private String thumbnailURL;
    private int birthDay;
    private int birthMonth;
    private int birthYear;
    private String gender;
    private String proxiedEmail;
    private String country;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String zip;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String profileURL;
    private int userID;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public UserSocialInfo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    /**
     * @return the socialID
     */
    public int getSocialID() {
        return socialID;
    }

    /**
     * @param socialID the socialID to set
     */
    public void setSocialID(int socialID) {
        this.socialID = socialID;
    }

    /**
     * @return the loginProvider
     */
    public String getLoginProvider() {
        return loginProvider;
    }

    /**
     * @param loginProvider the loginProvider to set
     */
    public void setLoginProvider(String loginProvider) {
        this.loginProvider = loginProvider;
    }

    /**
     * @return the loginProviderUID
     */
    public String getLoginProviderUID() {
        return loginProviderUID;
    }

    /**
     * @param loginProviderUID the loginProviderUID to set
     */
    public void setLoginProviderUID(String loginProviderUID) {
        this.loginProviderUID = loginProviderUID;
    }

    /**
     * @return the uID
     */
    public String getUID() {
        return UID;
    }

    /**
     * @param uID the uID to set
     */
    public void setUID(String uID) {
        UID = uID;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nickname
     */
    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    /**
     * @param nickname the nickname to set
     */
    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the photoURL
     */
    public String getPhotoURL() {
        return photoURL;
    }

    /**
     * @param photoURL the photoURL to set
     */
    public void setPhotoURL(String photoURL) {
        this.photoURL = photoURL;
    }

    /**
     * @return the thumbnailURL
     */
    public String getThumbnailURL() {
        return thumbnailURL;
    }

    /**
     * @param thumbnailURL the thumbnailURL to set
     */
    public void setThumbnailURL(String thumbnailURL) {
        this.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL;
    }

    /**
     * @return the birthDay
     */
    public int getBirthDay() {
        return birthDay;
    }

    /**
     * @param birthDay the birthDay to set
     */
    public void setBirthDay(int birthDay) {
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }

    /**
     * @return the birthMonth
     */
    public int getBirthMonth() {
        return birthMonth;
    }

    /**
     * @param birthMonth the birthMonth to set
     */
    public void setBirthMonth(int birthMonth) {
        this.birthMonth = birthMonth;
    }

    /**
     * @return the birthYear
     */
    public int getBirthYear() {
        return birthYear;
    }

    /**
     * @param birthYear the birthYear to set
     */
    public void setBirthYear(int birthYear) {
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    /**
     * @return the gender
     */
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    /**
     * @param gender the gender to set
     */
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    /**
     * @return the proxiedEmail
     */
    public String getProxiedEmail() {
        return proxiedEmail;
    }

    /**
     * @param proxiedEmail the proxiedEmail to set
     */
    public void setProxiedEmail(String proxiedEmail) {
        this.proxiedEmail = proxiedEmail;
    }

    /**
     * @return the country
     */
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    /**
     * @return the state
     */
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    /**
     * @param state the state to set
     */
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    /**
     * @return the zip
     */
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    /**
     * @param zip the zip to set
     */
    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    /**
     * @return the firstname
     */
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstname the firstname to set
     */
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastname
     */
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastname the lastname to set
     */
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the profileURL
     */
    public String getProfileURL() {
        return profileURL;
    }

    /**
     * @param profileURL the profileURL to set
     */
    public void setProfileURL(String profileURL) {
        this.profileURL = profileURL;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userID
     */
    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    /**
     * @param userID the userID to set
     */
    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
}
```

My xml files
User.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.entities.User" table="users">
        <id name="userID" type="long" column="userid">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" column="username" />
        <property name="password" column="password" />
        <property name="userID" column="userid" insert="false" update="false"/>
        <property name="createdDate" column="created_date" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

UserBooks.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.entities.UsersBooks" table="users_books">
        <id name="userID" type="long" column="user_id">
        </id>
        <property name="userID" column="user_id" insert="false" update="false"/>
        <property name="bookID" column="book_id" insert="false" update="false"/>
        <property name="permission" column="permissions" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

UserSocialInfo.java:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.entities.UserSocialInfo" table="user_social_info">
        <id name="socialID" type="long" column="social_id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="socialID" column="social_id" insert="false" update="false"/>
        <property name="loginProvider" column="login_provider" />
        <property name="loginProviderUID" column="login_provider_uid" insert="false" update="false"/>
        <property name="UID" column="uid" insert="false" update="false"/>
        <property name="nickname" column="nickname" />
        <property name="photoURL" column="photo_url" />
        <property name="thumbnailURL" column="thumbnail_url" />
        <property name="birthDay" column="birthday" />
        <property name="birthMonth" column="birthmonth" />
        <property name="birthYear" column="birthyear" />
        <property name="gender" column="gender" />
        <property name="proxiedEmail" column="proxied_email" />
        <property name="country" column="country" />
        <property name="state" column="state" />
        <property name="city" column="city" />
        <property name="zip" column="zip" />
        <property name="firstname" column="firstname" />
        <property name="lastname" column="lastname" />
        <property name="profileURL" column="profile_url" />
        <property name="userID" column="user_id" insert="false" update="false"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="fabulaFactory">
            <property name="connection.driver_class">
                 com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
             jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appname
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">
             user
        </property>
        <property name="connection.password">
            pwd
        </property>
            <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
            <!-- SQL dialect -->
            <property name="dialect">
                 org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
            </property>
            <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
            <property name="show_sql">false</property>
               <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping resource="com//hibernatexmlfiles//User.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com//hibernatexmlfiles//UsersBooks.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com//hibernatexmlfiles//UserSocialInfo.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

While executing the project i am getting an error like this:

```
  org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.fabulait.fabula.entities.User.userID
        at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.AbstractTuplizer.setIdentifier(AbstractTuplizer.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPersister.setIdentifier(BasicEntityPersister.java:2930)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:173)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:477)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:472)
        at com.service.UserService.storeSessionInfo(UserService.java:410)
        at com.web.LoginUser.doPost(LoginUser.java:122)
        at com.web.LoginUser.doGet(LoginUser.java:48)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:40)
        ... 32 more
```

So please give suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, keep in mind if you have turned auto-import to "false", you'll need to either fully qualify the classname, or set name

```
@Entity(name="User")
public class User {
}
```

As a suggestion, for most simpler queries, it's usually easier (and more performant since you don't have to parse the hql to an AST tree) to use criteria queries.  And in your case, you're just checking for any match.  So iterating through the results to compare the username is redundant to what is in your where clause.  The following is a much more efficient way to do what you're looking for:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
c.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
Number count = (Number) c.uniqueResult();
return (count.intValue() > 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
from User u where u.username=:username
```

I assume `User`  is the entity class (`@Entity`) mapped with table